# How to fix ‘net/http set header ORIGIN’ in Golang

Tags: go

I built a small piece of code with the function of getting information from a website,
and looks like it can't set orgin,
because with curl in php, I was able to get the data with http status of 200.
then I get 403.
Hope everyone helps. Thank you very much

```golang
req, err:= http.NewRequest("GET", "https://immortal.hydrax.net/0/BRlsM329RNjbSqlWnRF36A4Kf5jx6qlZmoeLnJRi9A6b", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36")
    req.Header.Set("Origin", "https://hydrax.net")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%s", resp.Status)
```

Output : 403 Forbiddenexit

Comment: It looks like that's a [forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) so you won't be able to set it programmatically.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, can you help me with a solution to this problem?
because I see the orgin curl still works

Answer (score 1):

No sense to set origin because it's can't be modified programmatically.
Probably your user agent header is not correct. Try this

```
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11`)
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked.

My code: is
`
 req.Header.Set("User-Agent",
"Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 73.0.3683.103 Safari / 537.36")
`

and it doesn't work.

Your work has been active. Thanks for helping me. Thanks very much

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)